# Getting an AJAX call to return a result on the same page in a DIV

Tags: php, ajax

I have a simply AJAX call as a part of an image upload form.  The page calls a PHP form which is supposed to then process the file upload and return a "successful" comment to the same page.

Currently, the script is working perfectly but when it returns the AJAX success string, it takes you to a new page and shows the AJAX output rather than showing it within the DIV on the same page.

To make it simpler, I've just cut out all of the PHP upload script and changed it to a simple echo output script - so I think it's a problem with the submit form page rather than the page that's called.  I have jQuery included in the submission page.

Here's the submit form:

```
<div id="uploadFormLayer">
<form id="uploadForm" action="../uploadtesties.sparkle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <input type="hidden" name="EID" value="<? echo $ElectionID; ?>">
</form>
</div>
<div id="targetLayer"></div>
```

Here's the AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "uploadtesties.sparkle",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
        $("#targetLayer").html(data);
        },
        error: function() 
        {
        }           
   });
 }));
});
</script>
```

The PHP page just says `<?php echo "Testing output"; ?>` for the moment.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)